# Appmaker: How can I get the ID of an item i just created, on client side?

Tags: javascript, server, client, google-app-maker

So my latest problem is the following:

I store an id(a foreign key) in a custom property. I want to set the Foreign Key field of an item I just created, to the stored custom property.

I am trying to achieve this in a server script, which looks like this:

```js
function setFKforCustomer(customerID, companyID)
{
  var query = app.models.Customer.newQuery();
  query.filters.Id._equals(customerID);
  var records = query.run();
  records[0].Company_fk=companyID;
}
```

I want to call this function from a client side script, which has to know the customer's ID, the id of the item I just created. I am not entirely sure I am approaching the problem from the right angle, so I am open to other ideas.
Thank you in advance (Markus)!

Answer (score 0):

The question of how to manage relationships in App Maker is probably one of the most asked questions. The official documentation for your specific use case is located here https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/relations#server_script. The answer would be as follows:

```
function setFKforCustomer(customerID, companyID)
{
  var customerRecord = app.models.Customer.getRecord(customerID);
  var companyRecord = app.models.Company.getRecord(companyID);
  customerRecord.YourCompanyRelationName = companyRecord; //the field in this case is not Company_fk but whatever the name is of the relation you set up in AM
  app.saveRecords([customerRecord]);
}
```